# Parsing a field in Kotlin, which can be a string or an object

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

I encountered a problem when receiving data from the backend that the resulting field (for example, "somethingField") could be either a String or an Object with two Int lists. How can you parse such data correctly? I'm using kotlinx.serialization .

```
@Serializable
data class SomeObject(
    ...
    val somethingField: String or SometingObject
    ...
)

@Serializable
data class SomethingObject(
    val list1: List<Int>,
    val list2: List<Int>,
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by using sealed classes. When the real type is one of the few available types, sealed classes are helpful in modeling constrained class hierarchies.

```
  import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable

  @Serializable
  sealed class SomethingField {
  @Serializable
  data class SomethingObject(val list1: List<Int>, val list2: List<Int>)             
  : SomethingField()

  @Serializable
  data class SomethingString(val value: String) : SomethingField()
  }


  @Serializable
  data class SomeObject(
  // ...
  val somethingField: SomethingField?,
  // ...
  )
```

You can then use it in your fragment or activity like this

```
  val someObject: SomeObject?  // ... deserialize from JSON

  when (someObject.somethingField) {
  is SomethingField.SomethingObject -> {
    // Handle SomethingObject case
    val list1 = someObject.somethingField.list1
    val list2 = someObject.somethingField.list2
  }
  is SomethingField.SomethingString -> {
    // Handle SomethingString case
    val stringValue = someObject.somethingField.value
  }
  }
```

This way, you can handle different cases based on the actual type of "somethingField".

Comment: When I respond (RESPONSE) from the server I receive: failed with exception: io.ktor.serialization.JsonConvertException: Illegal input: Expected class kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonObject as the serialized body of com...SomethingField, but had class kotlinx.serialization .json.JsonNull . Field yes, it can also be null

Comment: You need to add null checker(?) to the declaration in the fragment and the model data class, .

@Serializable
data class SomeObject(
    // ...
    val somethingField: SomethingField?,
    // ...
)
Fragment declaration
    val somethingField: SomethingField?

check updated answer

Comment: I did that, yes, but in the end I got different errors for different types, for example:
io.ktor.serialization.JsonConvertException: Illegal input: Expected class kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonObject as the serialized body of com...SomethingField, but had class kotlinx.serialization.json.JsonLiteral.

In the end, I decided to remake it for JsonElement and parse it - everything seems to be fine)

Comment: Ok I am glad you solved your issue.